# Forwarding C-c to a remote tmux session

Tags: ssh, tmux

I have `bind C-c new-window` (and other similar bindings, but only C-c is giving me an issue) in my .tmux.conf. On a local tmux session, the binding works as expected, but in a remote tmux session(over ssh) the binding does not appear to do anything.

Some searching suggested that it might be an issue with ssh intercepting ^C rather than sending it to the remote session, but ^C seems to otherwise work fine on the remote(for sending SIGINT to remote processes).

Anyone know what might be going wrong?

Comment: My immediate thought would be to copy over your tmux config